# ext4 mount: mount /dev/mmcblk0p2 on /SD failed: File exists?

Tags: filesystems, mount, ext4

If I try mounting the ext4 file system of `/dev/mmcblk0p2` into the blank directories I just created: `/SD` and also `/mnt/SD`, then the command line answers with:

```
sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p2 /SD
mount: mount /dev/mmcblk0p2 on /SD failed: File exists
```

If I try out a non-existent directory such as `/thispathdoesNotExist`

```
mount: mount point /thispathdoesNotExist does not exist
```

Unmount?

```
umount: /dev/mmcblk0p2: not mounted
```

and:

```
umount: /dev/mmcblk0: not mounted
```

Is that not contradictive?

**What does cause that problem, and how do I solve it?**

Comment: You may have FS corruption on the SD card you are mounting. Try running `fsck`

Comment: To help clear up: What is the command you used?

Comment: @Ajeh It works on a different Linux machine without any problems.

Comment: @jc__ I used `sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p2 /SD`.

Comment: @neverMind9 Guess we all left our crystal balls unplugged :) These details need to be mentioned in the question. Now, post the output of `df`

Comment: Is `/SD` a regular file (i.e. not a directory)?

Answer (score 0):

Just do `umount /dev/mmcblk0p2` and then again `mount /dev/mmcblk0p2 /SD`.

Hope it will work. Your partition is already mounted that needs to be unmounted before you mount it again.